# Confidence intervals for logistic fit in seaborn

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, statistics, seaborn

When the same dataset is plotted with logistic regression fit using seaborn in Python and ggplot2 in R, the confidence intervals are drastically different, though docs in both cases say they display 95% ci by default. What am I missing here?

R code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("MASS")
data(menarche)
ggplot(menarche, aes(x=Age, y=Menarche/Total)) + geom_point(shape=19) + geom_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial")
write.csv(menarche, file='menarche.csv')
```

Python code:

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('menarche.csv')
data['Fraction'] = data['Menarche']/data['Total']
sns.regplot(x='Age', y='Fraction', data=data, logistic=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn]
[image: ggplot2]

## Edit: binarization of response creates similar plot in ggplot2

Based on mwascom's comments I converted the data to binary response variable by creating and used it for comparison. Now the confidence intervals look similar and it appears that this is what seaborn is plotting when given the fraction of successes. I am yet to figure out when given the fraction of success as response variable, why the two are differing (the results of glm fit are same in terms of intercept and coefficient).

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
menarche = pd.read_csv('menarche.csv')

# Convert the data into binary (yes/no) response form
tmp = []
for ii, row in enumerate(menarche[['Age','Total', 'Menarche']] .as_matrix()):
    ages = [row[0]]*int(row[1])
    yes_idx = np.random.choice(int(row[1]), size=int(row[2]), replace=False)
    response = np.zeros((row[1]))
    response[yes_idx] = 1
    group = [ii] * int(row[1])
    group_data = np.c_[group, ages, response]
    tmp.append(group_data)

binarized = np.vstack(tmp)
menarche_b = pd.DataFrame(binarized, columns=['Group', 'Age', 'Menarche'])
menarche_b.to_csv('menarche_binarized.csv') # for feeding to R
menarche_b['intercept'] = 1.0
model = sm.GLM(menarche_b['Menarche'], menarche_b[['Age', 'intercept']], family=sm.families.Binomial())
result = model.fit()
result.summary()    
import seaborn as sns
sns.regplot(x='Age', y='Menarche', data=menarche_b, logistic=True)
plt.show()
```

produces the same curve (now the data points are plotted at 0 and 1).

```
data = read.csv('menarche_binarized.csv')
model = glm(Menarche ~ Age, data=data, family=binomial(logit))
model
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(data, aes(x=Age, y=Menarche))+stat_smooth(method="glm", family=binomial(logit))
```

now produces what looks similar to the seaborn output (similar confidence intervals).

Comment: The R code you show does not produce the graph you show. For one thing, your `y` should be `y=Menarche/Total`, not `y=Menarche/Total-Menarche`

Comment: @DavidRobinson Thanks for correcting - I had copied the wrong line from my terminal.

Comment: You shouldn't be fitting a logistic regression here, it doesn't look like you have binomial data.

Comment: @mwaskom I used a sample dataset in the MASS package taken from Milicer, H. and Szczotka, F. (1966) and the Menarche column gives the number of females in that age group who reached menarche.  It is commonly used for logistic regression example and the fit is visibly good.

Comment: Yes but here you're passing a proportion as the response variable, when logistic regression should be fit to successes and failures.

Comment: The proportion is that of successes and that is what the logistic function fits (approximating the probability of success). According to definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Definition_of_the_logistic_function I do not see anything wrong with that and both statsmodels (assuming that is what seaborn uses for the fit) and R seem to get it right.